# Maven pom.xml inheriting dependencies from spring-boot-starter-parent is not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I have created a Spring boot application for learning purpose.

I had my configurations in default application.properties file.

**src/main/resources/application.properties**

```
server.port=8761
```

This was working fine.

Later I decided to change configurations to application.yml file

**src/main/resources/application.yml**

```
server:
 port: 1112
```

From Spring documentation:

> Create a file called application.yml and stick it in the root of your
>   classpath, and also add snakeyaml to your dependencies (Maven
>   coordinates org.yaml:snakeyaml, already included if you use the
>   spring-boot-starter).

My pom.xml is inheriting from parent spring-boot-starter as below.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Since parent `pom.xml` has `org.yaml:snakeyaml` depedencies, I have not included any dependency in pom and tried running application.

But now values from `application.yml` file is not taken in account, instead application is using default port.

When I added the snakeyaml dependency explicitly in `pom.xml`, `application.yml` values are considered.

Also I dont think parent pom is missing the dependency, because when I added snakeyaml explicitly I am getting below warning in eclipse

```
Overriding managed version 1.17 for snakeyaml
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ServiceDiscovery</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ServiceDiscovery</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.SR5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: The parent did not define any dependency only dependencyManagement. So when not defining any dependency in your project you did not even have the Annotation @SpringBootApplication. So you need at least      spring-boot-starter as dependency which will activate auto config and yaml.

Comment: It’s included by spring-boot-starter), not spring-boot-starter-parent. Which starter are you depending on in your Pom?

Comment: I have added my pom.xml.

Comment: Dependencies looks OK. Could you add your Java Class which starts the eureka server and show your Java classes package structure? Maybe a look at this sample project helps (there is a eureka module): https://github.com/mszalbach/cloudbook.

Comment: First why are you adding slf4j api and simple in two different versions..Spring boot contains already everything for logging..so no need for that...just remove those deps. Furthermore spring boot contains also correct versions for reading yml files so no need to add snakyaml...dependency...explicit...so remove that too...

Answer (score 4):

My org.yaml:snakeyaml comes from spring-boot-starter-web (mvn dependency:tree command)

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
```

here is the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Presumably it is in other spring-boot-starter modules that include spring-boot-starter.

You do not need the

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```